# How to get an HTML element added from a dynamic array in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, observable

I have a list of items displayed in HTML from a Dynamic array as async. When I try to add a new item to the array, I want to select and get that item as an HTML element from DOM. How can I do that? When I try to get the item with a specific id, the DOM is not rendered with the item yet. I used ViewChild, but it returns undefined.

For example:

I have an array of vehicles as Dynamic Observable. I am trying to add a new item and get that item as an html element using the `id`. How can I do that?

```js
  @ViewChild('span') span: HTMLElement;
  vehicles:Observable<any[]> = [
    {'name':'test1', 'id': 1},
    {'name':'test2', 'id': 2},
    {'name':'test3', 'id': 3},
  ]
  pushData() {
    this.vehicles
         .pipe(
         tap(() => vehicles.push({
      name: 'test10',
      id: 4
    })

    const element:HTMLElement = document.getElementById("4");
    console.log(element)
    
    // console.log(this.span.id===4)
  }
```

```html
    <div *ngFor='let vehicle of vehicles | async'>
      <span #span id="{{vehicle.id}}">{{vehicle.name}}<br></span>       
    </div>
    <button (click)="pushData()">Push Data</button>
```

Comment: Simple stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-async-pipe-ngfor-sz1hbu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
In the above code I don't have as an Observable. But, I am trying to get the element just added to the DOM

Comment: I am looking for something which has immediate subscription like https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhjv43?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-component%2Fmy-component.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment that you need the HTML element which you newly added, for that you need wait for sometime(use `setTimeout`) so that element is reflected to `DOM`.

```
pushData() {
    this.vehicles
         .pipe(
         tap(() => vehicles.push({
      name: 'test10',
      id: 4
    })

  setTimeout(() => {
    const element:HTMLElement = document.getElementById("4");
    console.log(element)
  }, 50);
    
    // console.log(this.span.id===4)
  }
```

Here is the code for the to get the elements based on the `ViewChildren` changes.

Updated TS:

```
    @ViewChildren('vehicleElement') vehicleItems!: QueryList<HTMLElement>;
    
      vehicles = [
        { name: 'test1', id: 1 },
        { name: 'test2', id: 2 },
        { name: 'test3', id: 3 },
      ];
    
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.vehicleItems?.changes.subscribe((elements: QueryList<HTMLElement>) => {
          console.log(elements); // all elements
          console.log(elements.last); // last elements
        });
      }

  push() {
    this.vehicles.push({
      name: 'test10',
      id: 4,
    });
    // console.log(document.getElementById("4"))
  }
```

HTML Template:

```
<section class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"*ngFor='let vehicle of vehicles' >
    <span #vehicleElement id="{{vehicle.id}}">{{vehicle.name}}<br></span>       
    </div>
</section>

<button (click)="push()">Push data</button>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood or I didn't explain correctly. I want the HTML element which is added to the DOM from the new push using the id.

Comment: okay, let me update it

Comment: Thanks for updating. I tried SetTimeout(), but it's not a good user experience.  I am trying to select the element which is just added to the DOM and that will trigger an event. I am looking for something immediate subscription. Something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhjv43?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-component%2Fmy-component.component.ts

Comment: @tangel updated based on the ViewChildren

Answer (score 0):

I feel you're looking for BehaviorSubject

```
  vehicles:BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject([
    {'name':'test1', 'id': 1},
    {'name':'test2', 'id': 2},
    {'name':'test3', 'id': 3},
  ])
  pushData() {
    this.vehicles.next([...this.vehicles.value,{
      name: 'test10',
      id: 4
    }])
    setTimeout(()=>{
      const element:HTMLElement |null= document.getElementById("4");
      console.log(element)
  
    })
  }
```

The setTimeout it's necessary because you need "wait" Angular "repaint" the divs before check it.

If you don't like so much the setTimeout, You can also use [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

```
//inject in constructor de ChangeDetecteorRef
constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef){}

pushData() {
    this.vehicles.next([...this.vehicles.value,{
      name: 'test10',
      id: 4
    }])
    this.cdr.detectChanges(); //<--force Angular see changes
    const element:HTMLElement |null= document.getElementById("4");
    console.log(element)
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

1st why is your getElememtById function input param is a number 4. It should be string "4"

Else:
The DOM isn't rendered yet.
You can probably use Lifecycle hooks like:

```
ngAfterViewInIt()
```

Inside which you can try grabbing the html element.

Comment: You were right about the ID, but I posted it just as a rough code. I know about the getElementById and ngAfterViewInit(). I think you didn't understand the question. I am looking for something immediate after the element is added. Anyway, thanks.